# Which metric should I use to assess the quality of the clusters?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, clustering, metric, umap

I have a model that outputs a latent **N-dimensional embedding** for all data points, trained in a way that clusters data-points from the same class together, while being separated from other clusters belonging to other different classes.

The N-dimensional embedding is projected down to 2D using UMAP. At each epoch, I wish to test the **clustering capability** of the model on these 2D projections for use as validation accuracy. I have the labels for each class.

How should I proceed?

[image: UMAP Projection]

Answer (score 2):

You can compute [Silhouette Coefficient](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) for your aim. Its values [mean](https://towardsdatascience.com/silhouette-coefficient-validating-clustering-techniques-e976bb81d10c):

> 1: Means clusters are well apart from each other and clearly distinguished.
>
> 0: Means clusters are indifferent, or we can say that the distance between clusters is not significant.
>
> -1: Means clusters are assigned in the wrong way.

Other measures, such as [purity and mutual information](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html), are also possible by computing

> an external criterion that evaluates how well the clustering matches the gold standard classes

Answer (score 1):

One more popular metric for this is the [Davies Bouldin Score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.davies_bouldin_score.html#sklearn.metrics.davies_bouldin_score).

You can also take a look at the clustering metrics in [scikit documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics).